# Printing out a rose tree...?

Tags: string, haskell, tree, show

I am currently learning Haskell in one of my online classes at the university. I now have to write a program that can work with a rose tree.
Right now it looks like this:

```
data Rose a = Rose a [Rose a]

testTree1 = Rose 4 [Rose 5 [Rose 1 [], Rose 2 [Rose 7 [], Rose 8 []], Rose 3 []], Rose 6 []]

class Pretty a where
    pretty :: a -> String


instance Pretty (Rose a) where
    pretty (Rose v []) = "Test"
    pretty (Rose v t ) = "Test" ++ (concat(map ("\n+--"++) (map (pretty) t)))
```

On calling `putStrLn (pretty (testTree1))` the result should look like this:

```
4
+-- 5
|   +-- 1
|   +-- 2
|   |   +-- 7
|   |   +-- 8
|   +-- 3
+-- 6
```

My current function has the following result:

```
Test
+--Test
+--Test
+--Test
+--Test
+--Test
+--Test
+--Test
```

So I have these two questions.

1. How can I put the real value of `v` in the String instead of the placeholder `Test`, when I don't know which type the `v` will have?
2. I don't understand why the `Test`s in my result all have the same alignment. Of course I am not  using the `|`    yet, but shouldn't the `+--` appear more than one time in some lines?

Thx for your help :)

Comment: One question per post.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the value of `v` in the output, then `Rose a` only has a `Pretty` instance if `a` does as well, in which case you can use `pretty` to convert `v`.

```
instance Pretty a => Pretty (Rose a) where
    pretty (Rose v []) = pretty v
    pretty (Rose v t ) = pretty v ++ concat(map ("\n+--"++) (map pretty t)))
```

For your example, you also need to provide a concrete type for `testTree1` and to define an appropriate instance for `Pretty`. For example,

```
testTree1 :: Rose Int
testTree1 = ...

instance Pretty Int where
    pretty = show
```